# How to remove duplicates in a listbox VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates in a ListBox which is populated by a query pull. I use this code to prevent adding duplicates in VB 6.0 but does not work when converted over to VB.net. Is there a substitute method to prevent or remove duplicates.

```
colSchema = dr("Col_Schema").ToString
If Not lstSchema.Items.ToString.Contains(colSchema) Then
     lstSchema.Items.Add(New ListItem(colSchema))
End If
```

Comment: _If Not lstSchema.Items.Contains(colSchema) Then_ That ToString creates the error

Comment: Removing ToString does not solve the issue.  I get this below error. I was originally using it because it was not working without the ToString and it worked in VB6 with it on.

BC30311: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.

Comment: Is this a WinForms/WPF application or an ASP.NET one?

Comment: ASP.net - Visual Studio 15

Comment: I have added the asp.net tag to your post. Without it, it is likely that people would assume you are asking about a WinForms ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
colSchema = dr("Col_Schema").ToString
dim exists as boolean = false
for i as integer = 0 to lstSchema.items.count - 1
if lstSchema.items.item(i) = colSchema then
exists = true
end if
next
if exists = false then
lstSchema.Items.Add(New ListItem(colSchema))
end if
```

Comment: This code worked for me with an edit.

I had to add the Tostring function to make it work. 

lstSchema.items.item(i).ToString

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
lstSchema.Items.ToString
```

is converting Items to a string.  Items is most likely the type `ListBox.ObjectCollection` (if this is WinForms) or a similar collection type for other UI frameworks.  Calling ToString on such classes will end up calling Object.ToString, which just returns the name of the class.

Instead, try

```
lstSchema.Items.Contains(colSchema)
```

If that does not work for some reason, please update your question explaining exactly what you were trying to solve by calling ToString.